# Does the test set is used to update weight in a deep learning model with keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm wondering if the result of the test set is used to make the optimization of model's weights. I'm trying to make a model but the issue I have is I don't have many data because they are medical research patients. The number of patient is limited in my case (61) and I have 5 feature vectors per patient. What I tried is to create a deep learning model by excluding one subject and I used the exclude subject as the test set. My problem is there is a large variability in subject features and my model fits well the training set (60 subjects) but not that good the 1 excluded subject. 
So I'm wondering if the testset (in my case the excluded subject) could be used in a certain way to make converge the model to better classify the exclude subject?

Comment: No, no, no, and no. Don't even use the test set to train a model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the test data of your data set in your training process. If your training data is not enough, one approach using a lot during this days(especially for medical images) is **data augmentation**. So I highly recommend you to use this technique in your training process. [**How to use Deep Learning when you have Limited Data**](https://medium.com/nanonets/how-to-use-deep-learning-when-you-have-limited-data-part-2-data-augmentation-c26971dc8ced)  is one of the good tutorial about data augmentation.

Comment: I don't think i can use data augmentation in my case because my 1D feature vect is coming from connectivity matrix. So the position of each value is meaningful.therefore they are not interchangeable

Comment: Maybe you can. You can augment your data and after that you get your connectivity matrix from the augmented data. I mean you don't have to augment the inputs of your network.

Comment: Yes, I can start with that. However I'm wondering if I increase my number of connectivity matrices per subject, as I exclude one subject in order to validate the model with data not including in the training process, How the model would be more performent to classify that excluded subject? I'm feeling like I miss something important :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I've got your point correctly. But this is the concept of the learning. Your system will learn with some data and then it should be able to predict new data(this new data some times can be the training data). This is the learning system challenge to make a better decision about unseen data.

Answer (score 0):

No , you souldn't use your test set for training to prevent overfitting  ,  if you use cross-validation principles you need exactly to split your data into three datasets  a train set which you'll use to train your model , a validation set to test different value of your  hyperparameters , and a test set to finally test your model , if you use all your data for training, your model will overfit obviously.

One thing to remember deep learning work well if you have a large and very rich datasets